# Archiving lucene indices

Tags: logging, lucene, compression, zip

Have the use case, where data is indexed via lucene for searching. For every 12 hours the current index is archived in a zip and a new index is started afresh. Since our data inflow rate is pretty high, we need to do the zipping to help storage. We use java.util.zip for zipping and unzipping while searching.

Now the problem is when some one searches across the data over the past week, huge time is taken to unzip. Would be great if some one can suggest me some better and faster ways to unzip. I am considering 7-zip's LZMA, but some inputs would be of great use. At the same time, is zipping the right approach? Do I have a choice for it? We have a java code base and your inputs are awaited.

Comment: are you unzipping your past 12-hours indexes at every request?

Comment: No! When the need arises. If the user asks for 100 results and I get 100 in the first index, then I need not do it. In case he is paginating to 200 and I don't get the desired results in the open index, then I should open up the archive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LZMA has better compression, but will decompress even slower.

You can go in the other direction and accept not-as-good compression in order to get faster decompression.  You can look at [lz4](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/) for that.  It decompresses about four to five times as fast, but compresses to something about 50% larger (your mileage may vary).  Though there is a high compression (HC) mode for lz4 that spends more time compressing and does better, but still decompresses very fast.

Answer (score 1):

The following library decompress faster then lzma with similar compression ratio

http://code.google.com/p/lzham/